# SQL Server update query that only update table itself not indexes

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I need to write a query that update only table not indexes
because I want to update an `int` field and don't need to 10 huge index to be updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [Filtered Indexes](http://sqlfool.com/2009/04/filtered-indexes-what-you-need-to-know/) are what you're looking for.

This is a `SQL Server 2008` feature that lets you create an index that only applies to certain values in a column.

Comment: How does this apply to the OP's case? Are you suggesting that they drop their indexes and replace them all with filtered indexes that won't match either the "before" or "after" values of the update? Another option I suppose but seems like it wouldn't be suitable except in very niche cases to me.

Comment: It's hard to say why the OP doesn't want the indexes updated since it's not specified in the question. Just proposing this as something that might accomplish what they really want to do.

Comment: True - Actually the whole concept in the OP doesn't really make sense. Presumably the indexes were added as they were useful for queries so why would you want them to be wrong!

Comment: Should be a comment then if intent is unknown (to ask). My take on the question is that OP is concerned about write performance because of internal index maintenance. I assume with 10 indexes OP knows all about indexing on a table.

Comment: @gbn It turns out that my assumptions are different than yours.

Answer (score 6):

If the `int` field is included in any of the index definitions then they will have to be updated too.

SQL Server won't allow the base table to have one value and the indexes another for obvious data integrity reasons.

If the `int` field is not included in any of the index definitions then only the table will be updated anyway.

You can disable the indexes but to re-enable them involves rebuilding the whole index.

Comment: +1 @SnowStorm: SQL Server is not dBase - you cannot update the data but ignore the indices....

Comment: This is not entirely true with SQL2k8 which allows filtered indexes.

Comment: Not really relevant. The general point that if the value being updated in the base table also exists in an index then both need to be updated still holds.

Comment: Agreed, but your answer states that "SQL Server won't allow the base table to have one value and the indexes another". Since it's possible for the filtered index to contain only a subset of the values in the table, then your statement isn't entirely true. Maybe I'm just misreading your meaning though.

Comment: All I meant was that where SQL Server is storing multiple copies of the same data it won't allow this redundancy to cause anomalies where a query will return one value if one index is used and a different one if another index is used.

Comment: @Crappy Coding Guy: you're being pedantic. If Martin added "row for row" this would be OK but I'd expect this to be obvious. See http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=bleeding+obvious

Comment: @gbn Turning this into name calling and insults is ridiculous. You're taking this way too seriously.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you *really* want to do

Keeping the index consistent with the table data is the [Consistency in ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Consistency). This is how SQL Server and ACID-compliant RDBMSes work.

There are cases such as bulk loads where you want to delay this Consistency. So if you have this use case, DROP or DISABLE the indexes.

If you disable the indexes:

- they will **never** be used for **any query**-
- all associated unique and foreign keys etc will be disabled too
- they are not maintained

If you DROP them, of course they can't be used either.

After your bulk load is finished, you enable or create the indexes/constraints again.

If this is what you really want then read MSDN:

- [Disabling Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177406.aspx)
- [Guidelines for Disabling Indexes and Constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177456.aspx)